# Trying to read a single column text file by two's to make a key-value pair in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

Working on a typical Python project of quizzing a user on state's capitals. Instead of just copying and creating my own dictionary I'm reading a text file. I have the portion of the quiz set up(I think) and I'm struggling with creating the actual key-value pairs. The text file looks like this:

Alabama

Montgomery

Alaska

Juneau

Arizona

Phoenix

Arkansas

Little Rock
etc....

I can't figure out how to read the first line as the key(state) and second line as the value(capital). Once I have the correct variables I will change what my main method calls. Any help or feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
    NUM_STATES = 5

    def make_dictionary():
        with open('state_capitals.txt', 'r') as f:
           d = {}
           for line in f:
               d[line.strip()] = next(f, '').strip()

    def main():
        d = make_dictionary()

        correct = 0
        incorrect = 0

        for count in range(NUM_STATES):
            state, capital = d.popitem()

        print('Enter a capital of ', state, '?', end = '')
        response = input() 
        if response.lower() == capital.lower():
            correct += 1
            print('Correct!')
        else:
             incorrect += 1
             print('Incorrect.')

        print('The number of correct answers is: ', correct)
        print('The number of incorrect answers is: ', incorrect)


    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the file as a string then do this

```
with open('state_capitals.txt', 'r') as f:
  file_ = f.read()

file_ = list(filter(lambda x:not x == "", file_.split("\n")))

keys = [key for index,key in enumerate(file_) if index%2 == 0]
values = [value for index,value in enumerate(file_) if not index%2 == 0]

dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I use this the error I'm getting shows up as: state = dictionary.popitem()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'popitem'. Which has been the error for a lot of different tries I've done.